# Can a sorted bar chart be a way for check if two matrices have similarities or not?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

If I have two matricies `X` and `Y` and I want to complare and see how similar they are. I can use $L_2$ norm:

```
J = abs(X-Y)
```

But if `X` are just one step at one side, then $J$ will be very large. So this method is very sensitive for variations.

**Question:**

Is there a robust method for "measure" the smimilarities between two matricies?

**Example:**

Let's give you an image

[image]

And we have just converted it to Local Binary Pattern image

```
imshow(uint8(lbp(rgb2gray(imread('orange.jpg')))));
```

[image]

With this MATLAB code. Assume that the image `X` is our matrix.

```
function X = lbp(X)
  % Get the size
  [m, n] = size(X);
  
  % Temporary matrix
  Y = X;
  
  for i = 2:m-1
    for j = 2:n-1
      X = turn_9_elements_binary(X, Y, i, j);
    end
  end
  
end

function X = turn_9_elements_binary(X, Y, i, j)
  center_element = X(i, j);
  binary_value = 0;
  binary_counting = 0;
  coordinates_i = [-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0];
  coordinates_j = [-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1];
  for k = 1:8
    % If the outer 8 elements are higher then the center element
    if(center_element <= Y(coordinates_i(k)+i, coordinates_j(k)+j))        
      % Shift the binary value
      binary_value = bitor(binary_value, bitshift(1, binary_counting));
    else
      binary_value = bitor(binary_value, bitshift(0, binary_counting));
    end
    binary_counting = binary_counting + 1;
  end
  
  % Save the binary value
  X(i, j) = binary_value;
end
```

**Question:**

Do you think that a bar chart can describe the difference between matrices? Let's assume that one image is a matrix. Let's call them `X, Y, Z`

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I run this MATLAB script.

```
function test_lbp()
  close all
  create_bar_chart_of_file_name('X.png');
  create_bar_chart_of_file_name('Y.png');
  create_bar_chart_of_file_name('Z.png');
end

function create_bar_chart_of_file_name(file_name)  
  % One matrix 
  X = rgb2gray(imread(file_name));

  % Use Local Binary Pattern
  Xlbp = lbp(X);

  % Turn them into vectors 
  Xlbp_v = reshape(Xlbp, size(Xlbp, 1)*size(Xlbp, 2), 1);

  % Sort them
  Xlbp_v_sort = sort(Xlbp_v);

  % Plot them with bar chart 
  figure
  bar(Xlbp_v_sort);
  title(file_name)
end
```

I can see that there are differences between them.

Can sorting a bar chart be a way for determine if the matrix have similarities or not?

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem. I think you should start with defining the criteria of similarity for your specific application. Let's say two matrices have a row of ones and all other elements are zeroes. Are they similar? It would be nice to get more context as well, maybe the problem that you are trying to solve already has a solution.

Comment: @Vasya Do you think eigenvalues and eigenvectors can come in handy here?